# Exclude some styling from Vuetify2 when using Vite resolver: VuetifyResolve

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vite

I have a problem with Vite dev server, when using VuetifyResolve it seems Vite adds all of Vuetify's styles to the DOM (which I guess is intended), but in my setup I need to be able to exclude all Vuetify styles or maybe just the _reset.scss from dev server because they are imported in my css file. The reason for this is, that in my setup I have a lot of old styling, that gets overridden when vuetify styling is not wrapped in a wrapper class.

Vite build works fine, because styles are not implemented to the DOM.

I am using Vue 2.7, Vuetify 2.6, and Vite 4.2.

My vite.config looks like this:

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { VuetifyResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      ".mjs",
      ".js",
      ".ts",
      ".tsx",
      ".jsx",
      ".json",
      ".vue"
    ],
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '~': fileURLToPath(new URL('./node_modules', import.meta.url)),
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  external: [
    'vuetify/src/styles/main.sass',
    'vuetfiy/dist/vuetify.min.css'
  ],
  build: {
    cssMinify: true,
    minify: true,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    sourcemap: true,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    outDir: 'wwwroot/dist',
    assetsDir: '',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app: resolve(__dirname, './src/main.js'),
        dashboard: resolve(__dirname, './src/components/Views/dashboard/index.js'),
        login: resolve(__dirname, './src/components/Views/Login/index.js'),
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
        assetFileNames: 'app.css',
        sourcemap: true
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    Components({
      resolvers: [
        VuetifyResolver()
      ],
    }),
    splitVendorChunkPlugin()
  ]
})
```

Please let me know if you need any more information